# Date Only format with BCS

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, formatting

I have created an External Content Type through SharePoint Designer. One of the fields that I'm getting from my database is a DateTime column. In SharePoint, however, I want to format this as a Date only. At the moment it's coming through as

> 2011-05-06 00:00:00z

I want something like:

> 2011-05-06

Or ideally:

> 06-05-2011

It sounds really simple, but I can find little information on how to achieve this. Have I missed something really obvious? Is this achievable? I do not want to have to modify the database (that will take time and administration)

EDIT: the particular problem is a date column within the External Data Picker, and the External Content type is only being used for an External Data column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that this is possible at this time, which is annoying. Kudos for Roel for his tip on doing this for an External List.

Answer (score 2):

There is an article in the DUET info on MSDN that shows you how to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg271157.aspx

I think you can do it as follows as well (since an external content type is still a content type; however I have not tested this):
 - Create your external list from the
   external content type
 - Go into the external lists you have
   created for your site in sharepoint
   designer
 - In the right hand corner you can see
   the views. Your external list should
   have a default view. Click on it and
   the file should open in sharepoint
   designer.

Look for a snippet like this:

```
<XmlDefinition>
            <View Name="{62A0ABCF-DF9D-45DD-985E-46ECDC9F5004}" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="SmartAppList" Url="/Lists/ghjghj/ReadList.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png">
                <Method Name="ReadList"/>
                <Query>
                    <OrderBy>
                        <FieldRef Name="Id"/>
                    </OrderBy>
                </Query>
                <ViewFields>
                    <FieldRef Name="Id" ListItemMenu="TRUE" LinkToItem="TRUE"/>
                    <FieldRef Name="Name"/>
                    <FieldRef Name="Description"/>
                    <FieldRef Name="ConfigurationXml"/>
                </ViewFields>
                <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
                <Aggregations Value="Off"/>
                <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
            </View>
        </XmlDefinition
```

>

- At the fieldref for your field you
  should be able to add the format
  attribute. This allows you to change
  the display of the date/time field.

Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543225.aspx for possible values.

Comment: Close, but not quite what I was looking for. I'm trying to get the DateTime to appear as a Date only in the External Picker control, and my External Content Type is only being used in an External Data column. This looks good for an External List itself (and is interesting!), but that's slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

From SharePoint designer:

List and Libraries -> Click on list -> Under Views tab -> Read List

Right click on the date field -> Edit formula

Replace:

`$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]`

With

`substring-before($thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name], ' ')`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SP.SE agentc! That's a nice answer. Hope you continue to explore our community. If you need help, don't hesitate to contact me or any other moderator. Cheers!

Comment: This worked on SP designer 2010, but I can't seem to get to this on SP designer 2013. The "Design" view appears to be completely missing.  Is there a way to do this on SP Designer 2013?