# BCS Date Only field on Update Form

Tags: bcs, form, date-time

I'm tasked with finding a method for Updating a field that is defined as Date in SQL, but rendered as DateTime through BCS (as there is no Date-only type).  On the Update form, I only want a Date Picker, not Date AND Time.  Can this be done with a custom field type?

Comment: Do you have infopath?

Answer (score 1):

I [asked this a while ago](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12322/date-only-format-with-bcs), but couldn't find any adequate way of doing it. I don't think that External Lists are exactly the same as a normal list, so I'm not convinced that a custom field type would work - but I don't think this was an idea that I'd tried. I also didn't try Infopath (mostly 'cos I hate InfoPath)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible:

have a look at this:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/fc9f1079-67f5-4484-927a-96625a03c98a

Taken from the link above explains well from scott:

> The matching of the .NET type to some sort of display control (e.g.,
>   System.String to Text) cannot be altered for the OOB External List. If
>   you do not like what you get, then you have the following options:
>
> 1. Change the underlying data type (for example, changing the DateTime in the database to varchar formatted as Date only)
>
>    1. Create custom InfoPath or ASPX forms with controls to render what you want
>    2. Create custom field types/field controls to render what you want
>    3. Use a FormatString property or RedererDefinition where the field type can be converted to a string representation easily
>    4. Create a .NET Assembly Connector and return custom data in the format you want
>    5. Create a custom web part and use the BCS object model to retrieve data, then format it as you want
>    6. Use custom XSLT and the External Data web parts to render the data

and

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/556cdba4-033d-49c1-9ea7-0307293f318e/

This is a question that is asked alot but has no real answer to it except for workarounds!

Hope this helps :)